# How to check if the checbox is checked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I need to check if the check-boxes are checked and from there save the rows of data that the user has selected into my database but I don't know how to even start.

That includes how to save the data to my database.

FYI: The check-boxes are inside of a 'GridView' and then inside of a 'ItemTemplate'.

If you're unsure about what I'm trying to achieve just ask and I'll try to make it clearer.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="TestCreation.aspx.vb" Inherits="SpellingBee.testcreation1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h1>Compile Your Tests</h1>

<asp:GridView ID="CreateTest" runat="server" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
        DataKeyNames="QuestionID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="QuestionSelector" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="QuestionID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="QuestionID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer" HeaderText="Answer" 
            SortExpression="Answer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
            SortExpression="Question" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubjectID" HeaderText="SubjectID" 
            SortExpression="SubjectID" />
        <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [QuestionID], [Answer], [Question], [SubjectID] FROM [Question]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:Button ID="QuestionCompiler" runat="server" Text="Compile Selected Questions" />

<h1>Preview Previous Tests</h1>

</asp:Content>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
Public Class testcreation1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            If Session.Item("User Type") <> "Teacher" Then
                Response.Redirect("/")
            End If

        End Sub

        Protected Sub QuestionCompiler_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles QuestionCompiler.Click



        End Sub
    End Class
    <h1>Preview Previous Tests</h1>

    </asp:Content>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want all checked `CheckBoxes`? You have to use `GridViewRow.FindControl` to get their references. You can use this little query in your save-function:

```
IEnumerable<GridViewRow> allCheckedRows = CreateTest.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(row => ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("QuestionSelector")).Checked);

foreach(GridViewRow checkedRow in allCheckedRows)
{
    // implement the save function for this row
    int questionID = int.Parse(checkedRow.Cells[1].Text);
    // ...
}
```

Whoops, here is the VB.NET version:

```
Dim allCheckedRows = From row In CreateTest.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)()
                     Where DirectCast(row.FindControl("QuestionSelector"), CheckBox).Checked

For Each checkedRow As GridViewRow In allCheckedRows
    ' implement the save function for this row '
    Dim questionID As Int32 = Int32.Parse(checkedRow.Cells(1).Text)
    ' ... '
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked really well, appreciate the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the `Checked` attribute on the `Checkbox` object?

```
If QuestionSelector.Checked Then 
    DoSomething()
End If
```

Comment: is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: How do I then get the row from the checked text-box to store in my database?

Comment: @Callum Well, in that case you should start reading up on some basic tutorials, perhaps MSDN documentation. Googling "asp.net checkbox class reference" might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
if (QuestionSelector.Checked == true) {
   //Do Whatever
}
```

and also this:

**In C#:**

```
CheckBox chbx = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("QuestionSelector") as CheckBox;
   if (chbx != null && chbx.Checked){
      //Do Whatever
   }
```